# Regular expression that works in .net not working in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want get data from html with python shell .  this code is simple:

```
import re
s="<a><b>为什么你该去逛逛墓地</b></a>"
p=re.compile('(?<=<(\w+)>).*?(?=<(/\w+)>)',re.I|re.S)
m=p.findall(s)

error log:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    p=re.compile('(?<=<(\w+)>).*?(?=<(/\w+)>)',re.I|re.S)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 214, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\functools.py", line 258, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 274, in _compile
    return sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 497, in compile
    code = _code(p, flags)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 482, in _code
    _compile(code, p.data, flags)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\sre_compile.py", line 115, in _compile
    raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
```

sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: Is that the full traceback? Why are you trying to parse HTML with regex?

Comment: Never used python myself, but when I see `\w` outside of JavaScript native regex, I instantly think _does that need to be escaped?_

Comment: You can't use a variable length match inside a look-ahead/behind in python.  For more details, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I want get data from html with python shell

Comment: @Isaac It was probably copied over from a c# verbatim string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```
re.compile('(?:<[^>]*>\s*)+(.+?)(?:<[^>]*>\s*)+',re.I|re.S)
```